# parse JSON data in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON data in the following format,

```
[
    {
        "name": "France",
        "date_time": "2015-05-17 19:59:00",
        "dewpoint": "17",
        "air_temp": "10.8"
    },
    {
        "name": "England",
        "date_time": "2015-05-17 19:58:48",
        "dewpoint": "13",
        "air_temp": "10.6"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ireland",
        "date_time": "2015-05-17 19:58:50",
        "dewpoint": "15",
        "air_temp": "11.1"
    }
]
```

I have a Google map set up already for the Android app, so i have a pass the name value between two activity(GoogleMaps.java & WeatherInfo.java),  now when i click a point in Google Map, it will pass the name to WeatherInfo.java, i want get the weather data for that name.

for example: i click France point in the map, The WeatherInfo.class will get the name is "France" and print out the "date_time, dewpoint, air_temp" for that point.

My question is how can i get the Json data parsed only for the point i clicked in the map? Can anyone look at the for loop in my WeatherInfo.java class?

WeatherInfo.java

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);


                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String date_time = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                    String temp = c.getString(TAG_TEMP);
                    String dewpoint = c.getString(TAG_DEWPOINT);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_DATE, date_time);
                    contact.put(TAG_TEMP, temp);
                    contact.put(TAG_DEWPOINT, dewpoint);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: *how can i get the Json data parsed only for the point i clicked in the map?* just parse all of the JSON using a library, and retrieve the relevant data from the parsed result when you need it

Comment: Does contact list contain all of the locations as well as there date I.e France, England etc

Comment: the library i used, just think my for loop is not correct, can anyone look at my for loop in the class?

Comment: Yes, the contec list shows on the webpage is what i put on above, there only have one array, contains this three points name , date_time, dewpoint, air_temp.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)new JSONTokener(jsonStr).nextValue();

for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);             
    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
    String date = jsonObject.getString("date_time");
    ...
}
```

Or

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)new JSONTokener(jsonStr).nextValue();

for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);             
    City city = new City();
    city.name = jsonObject.getString("name");        
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your json starts with JsonArray [] not JSONObject {}

Comment: you are right, i was follow the link below to doing the class, i want to achieve something,but just because of my json data formate is different with the tutorial, then i got lost. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Hi @vrbsm, how can i say if i get the passed data from GoogleMaps is France, than i want to print the weather info(date_time, dewpoint, air_temp) for name = "France" only, how can i achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

You could use Jackson json parser as follows:-

you will need a value object for the point data.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Point {

    private final String name;
    private final String dateTime;
    private final int dewpoint;
    private final double airTemp;

    @JsonCreator
    public Point(@JsonProperty("name") final String name, @JsonProperty("date_time") final String dateTime, @JsonProperty("dewpoint") final int dewpoint, @JsonProperty("air_temp") final double airTemp) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.dewpoint = dewpoint;
        this.airTemp = airTemp;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public int getDewpoint() {
        return dewpoint;
    }

    public double getAirTemp() {
        return airTemp;
    }

}
```

Then this Jackson Object Mapper

```
// 2. Convert JSON to Java object
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Point[] points = mapper.readValue(new File("points.json"), Point[].class);

for (Point point : points) {
    System.out.println("" + point.getName());
    System.out.println("" + point.getDateTime());
    System.out.println("" + point.getDewpoint());
    System.out.println("" + point.getAirTemp());            
}
```